# Colorimetric test for methanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Will adding dilute potassium permanganate to impure methanol in alkaline conditions work as a good colorimetric method? I am planning to produce salicylic acid from methyl salicylate (by hydrolysing the ester and producing methanol), and was wondering how I can show that the reaction goes to completion under alkaline conditions. If not, what would be a good method to show this?

Comment: Usually, methanol is used in excess, so checking for methanol isn't terribly useful. You can check for salicylic acid with $\ce{FeCl3}$, which forms a purple complex with salicylic acid. See [here](http://old.iupac.org/publications/cd/medicinal_chemistry/Practica-I-11.pdf). Permanganate may work for methanol, but it is such a strong oxidant, I'd be worried about it reacting indiscriminately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However I think you've got it back to front about the reaction, I'm hydrolysing the ester, so producing methanol. Also iron(III) chloride will form a purple complex with both the reactant and product since they both have a phenol group. However, you may be right about other reactions occurring due to its oxidising ability and I hadn't thought about that so I'll have a think about that, thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, I misread. My bad. Are planning on titrating or just doing a qualitative test for methanol? Because just qualitatively testing for the presence of methanol won't tell you anything about the completeness of the reaction. Also, I thought it was the chelating effect of the carboxylate and the phenol that caused the purple color.

Comment: Nevermind, you're right, ferric chloride tests positive for all phenols with a purple color.

Comment: Some form of quantitative test - I was thinking of trying colorimetry with the potassium permanganate reaction. Iron(III) chloride will turn purple with a phenol without a carboxylic acid (I've also tried it with both reactant and product; both go purple), but I might be able to use a ligand exchange to differentiate between the 2 compounds as methyl salicylate will only be a mono-dentate ligand, then use colorimetry.